How to improve on current code to Find if specific named sheets exist and delte them?
i have been doing some research and frankensteined  a few codes together from 2 resources and wanted to know if there was room to improve on the code i put together. i had an older code that was a bit clunky.
sources:
https://excelchamps.com/vba/delete-sheet/#:~:text=Each%20sheet%20has%20a%20name%2C%20and%20you%20can,code%20would%20be%3A%20Sub%20vba_delete_sheet%28%29%20Sheets%28%22Data%22%29.Delete%20End%20Sub
https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/delete-clear-worksheet/#:~:text=With%20On%20Error%20Resume%20Next%20you%20can%20tell,if%20so%20delete%20it.%3A%20If%20RangeExists%28%22Sheet1%22%29%20Then%20Sheets%28%22Sheet1%22%29.Delete
Code:
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim mySheet1 As Variant
Dim mySheet2 As Variant
Dim mySheet3 As Variant
Dim mySheet4 As Variant
Dim mySheet5 As Variant


mySheet1="S363"
mySheet2="non"
mySheet3="promos"
mySheet4="All Filtered"
mySheet5="Final Send"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If mySheet1 = ws.Name Then
      ws.Delete
 ElseIf  mySheet2 = ws.Name Then
      ws.Delete
ElseIf  mySheet3= ws.Name Then
      ws.Delete
ElseIf  mySheet4 = ws.Name Then
      ws.Delete
ElseIf  mySheet5 = ws.Name Then
      ws.Delete
    End If
Next ws

‘All other instructions here
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


You can try this code:
Sub DelShs()
    Dim sh As Variant
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each sh In Array("S363", "non", "promos", "All Filtered", "Final Send")
        Worksheets(sh).Delete
    Next sh
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

If you are sure that all specified sheets exist, you can delete them in one go:
Worksheets(Array("S363", "non", "promos", "All Filtered", "Final Send")).Delete


since there are multi people on teh team i work with, most of them do something differently  + when onboarding new members, ive found at times sometimes 1 or more of the sheets get manually removed or left in place before we start our normal process.  So i have been trying to figure out safe guards incase they any amount of these tabs are left behind.
